# While using position absolute my background disappears

Tags: html, css

I have a jumbotron that i want it to have a 100% of height and for that i am using position absolute, but when i use my background disappears. What could i do to solve this issues. I tried many things i read on different sites but non of them work. Thank you in advanced
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Purgase Tracker - Track Santa!</title>

     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron map">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 
    90deg,
    #FFFFFF, 
    #FFFFFF 18px,
    #CA1D20 0px, 
    #CA1D20 28px 
    );
}
h1{
  font-size: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
}
h2{
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  margin: auto;
}
.jumbotron.timer{
  width: 58%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #669900;
}
.timertxt{
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #2980b9 ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  text-align: center;
}
.space{
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
} 
.timertxtc{
  width: 25%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.timertxtc:last-child{
  padding: 0;
}
h4{
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
/* TRADITIONS */
.jumbotron.map{
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #669900;
}
```

Comment: can you add code snippet ?

Comment: Just run the code as a snippet and I don't see any problem. Are you sure?

Comment: i see there's no problem also when i tried it at jsfiddle

Comment: @Dekel Essam i've just tryed it on jsfiddle and it's not working. there is a green jumbotron and no background

Comment: @YYahyaEssam Essam i've just tryed it on jsfiddle and it's not working. there is a green jumbotron and no background

Comment: @Moloco your Css Code has some unused classes or the html code is uncompleted .  and I don't understand which background you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div to have height 100% and width 100% body also needs to have height as 100% and width as 100% which is a bad practice

instead you can consider using viewport widths and viewport height

check the following snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 18px, #CA1D20 0px, #CA1D20 28px);
}
/* TRADITIONS */

.jumbotron.map {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #669900;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron map">
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using position absolute for child element, your parent element (BODY) no longer have height, which was given earlier by .jumbotron.map (positioned static). Just add height: 100%; to your body tag :).

Comment: I've just copied your code and tried. It's working. Try again. Remember; height: 100%; to body tag

Comment: i did add height 100% but its not working can you send me the code?